# How to use CURL instead of file_get_contents?

Tags: php, curl, file-get-contents

I use `file_get_contents` function to get and show external links on my specific page.

In my local file everything is okay, but my server doesn't support the `file_get_contents` function, so I tried to use cURL with the below code:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}

 echo file_get_contents_curl('http://google.com');
```

But it returns a blank page. What is wrong?

Comment: what's the [curl_error](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-error.php) say?

Comment: your coding is working, maybe curl is not install ? check out in phpinfo()

Comment: You are doing no error checking and then wondering why no errors show up. That's.... unwise.

Comment: I suspect that if your hosting provider has disabled fopen wrappers (needed for `file_get_contents()` to work) then they have not installed curl either.  If it's your own server, then enable `allow_url_fopen` in your PHP config.

Comment: in phpinfo `cURL support  enabled`

Comment: in Local get me this message : `The document has moved here.`

Answer (score 89, accepted):

try this:

```
function file_get_contents_curl($url) {
    $ch = curl_init();

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       

    $data = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $data;
}
```

Comment: Curl returns empty Content.. how can i avoid this?

Comment: @151291 adding below configuration worked for me : 
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);

Answer (score 11):

This should work

```
function curl_load($url){
    curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}

$url = "http://www.google.com";
echo curl_load($url);
```

Comment: This code will not behave exactly like file_get_contents. Your code will not follow redirects, file_get_contents does that.

Answer (score 4):

//You can try this . It should work fine.

```
function curl_tt($url){

$ch = curl_init();

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

return $data;
}
echo curl_tt("https://google.com");
```

Answer (score 4):

I encountered such a problem accessing Google Drive content via the direct link.

After calling file_get_contents returned 302 Moved temporarily

```
//Any google url. This example is fake for Google Drive direct link.
$url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0BxQKKJYjuNElbFBNUlBndmVHHAj";
$html = file_get_contents($url);
echo $html; //print none because error 302.
```

With the code below it worked again:

```
//Any google url. This example is fake for Google Drive direct link.
$url = "https://drive.google.com/uc?id=0BxQKKJYjuNElbFBNUlBndmVHHAj";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);  
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 3);     
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
$html = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);

echo $html;
```

I tested it today, 03/19/2018

Comment: `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);`
and `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);` got my tripped up for a long time, too.  Great catch!