# PHP Simple HTML DOM can't read "data-src" or "img src" without http: in path

Tags: php

I'm working with PHP Simple HTML DOM and just discovered it can't read images from `data-src` attribute or `<img src` without http: eg; `<img src="//static.mysite.com/123.jpg">`

Is there any way to make it happen?

My code is:

```
if($htm->find('img')){
foreach($htm->find('img') as $element) {
        $raw = file_get_contents_curl($element->src);
        $im = @imagecreatefromstring($raw);
        $width = @imagesx($im);
        $height = @imagesy($im);
        if($width>500&&$height>=350){
    $hasimg = '1';
        echo '<img src=\'' .$element->src. '\'>';
        }

} // end foreach
} // end if htm
```

Comment: And what's the problem if you specify `http` ?

Comment: Actually the problem is where `http:` is missing.

Comment: If site doesn't response without `http` then write it manually in foreach loop

Comment: Try putting a `die();var_dump($raw);` after `file_get_contents_curl(...);` and verify that that function is working correctly. I would guess you're not getting any errors because of all of the error suppression operators.

Comment: Its not the site URLs, Its about `http:` in img paths on remote URLs.

Comment: @AlexW The above function is working properly. But it doesn't respond to `<img dara-src="">` or img tag without `http:` in path.

Answer (score 11):

It works for me:

```
$doc = str_get_html('<img data-src="foo">');
echo $doc->find('img', 0)->getAttribute('data-src');
//=> outputs: foo
```

Answer (score 1):

```
echo $htm->find('img', 0)->getAttribute('data-src');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `file_get_contents_curl()` as a function you defined in your code, like the one in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540800/php-how-can-use-curl-instead-file-get-contents), you need to set the default protocol to use for cURL:

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROTOCOLS, CURLPROTO_HTTP);
```

That way, if the image `src` attribute has a protocol relative URL, cURL will just use HTTP.

Comment: Yes I'm using `file_get_contents_curl()`. I added the above line. It didn't solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Leaving out the protocol (http/https) is called "network path reference" and means that the protocol of the page the URL is embedded in should be used. This makes no sense with file_get_contents() or curl, because they are not aware of any page.

Long story short, you have to add the protocol yourself.

Try this:

```
$url=$element->src;
if (substr($url, 0, 2)=='//') $url='http:'.$url;
$raw=file_get_contents_curl($url);
```

Comment: Short story, you didn't understand the question :D

Comment: Your question is "Is there a any way to make that happen". The only what to make that happen is to add http or https yourself. What part did I not understand?

Comment: What I get from your answer is adding `http` to source url, which are already being used. What functions isn't doing is, failing to extract urls of images (from data-src tag or img tag without http in image paths) from provided html contents. eg `<img data-src="//static.zara.net/photos//2014/V/0/1/p/4806/029/406/2/w/1024/4806029406_9_1_1.jpg"
src="//static.zara.net/photos//2014/V/0/1/p/4806/029/406/2/w/1024/4806029406_9_1_1.jpg">`

Comment: I think that the extraction of the URL from the HTML content works just fine. The problem is that file_get_contents_curl() does not understand URLs without http: in front of it.

Comment: Yes Wolfgang Stengel got it. Plus I tried `file_get_contents_curl($element->data-src);` It didn't work either

Comment: Did you test it with a URL that starts with //?

Comment: @Waqas The example URLs you provided [are not valid URLs](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/8354/what-does-the-double-slash-mean-in-urls).

Comment: They are valid URLs in an HTML/browser context, but not for file_get_contents_curl().

Comment: Yes I tested `<img src="//path..">` and `<img data-src="//path..">` and `<img data-src="http://path..">` all are not working. Only `<img data-src="http://path..">` works.

Comment: It seems there are two problems here then. If you use <img src=""> your code needs to be $element->src. The attribute name and the member name need to be equal. Additionally, any kind of server side fetching of URLs will never work with URLs like "//path", you need to add http or https if it's missing.

Comment: Ok they are not valid, then I think its limitation of **Simple_html_dom.php** I'll have to quit on this :D

Comment: Or maybe not quit, but just add it yourself. Like everyone is recommending.

Comment: It's not a limitation of the DOM parser. You can var_dump($element->src) to see what comes out.