# file_get_contents/curl PHP Function Not Working For IP Address

Tags: php, apache, curl, file-get-contents, shared-hosting

My server contain a file at `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550/check.txt` and in which only `Online` is written. Now I am on my shared hosting and I want to get `Online` in my shared hosting php file for that I am using the below code in my shared hosting php file.

```
<?php
var_export(ini_get('allow_url_fopen'));
$uri = 'http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550/check.txt';
$result = file_get_contents($uri);
echo $result;
?>
```

But I am only getting `'1'` instead of `'1' Online`. So can you answer my why not working when I enter my server IP?

**Note:** And when I am adding `http://www.google.com` instead of `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550/check.txt` then I am getting whole Google page.

**Important Note:** I am able to open `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550/check.txt` in my web-browser directly via proxy means no firewall blocking is in my server (**Ubuntu Server 14.04 LTS**).

### UPDATE:

I also tried `CURL` and that's also not working with `http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550/check.txt` but working with `http://www.google.com`.

```
<?php
function curl_load($url){
    curl_setopt($ch=curl_init(), CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);
    return $response;
}
$url = "http://XX.XX.XX.XX:7550/check.txt";
echo curl_load($url);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use cUrl instead of file_get_contents.

Comment: I also used http://stackoverflow.com/a/8618788/3170029 but this one is also only working with URLs not IP... :-(