# where i can find file_get_contents() function and repalce it with Curl

Tags: function, curl, file-get-contents

where i can find file_get_contents()  function and repalce it with Curl

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Warning
>
> Message: file_get_contents() [function.file-get-contents]: https://
>   wrapper is disabled in the server configuration by allow_url_fopen=0
>
> Filename: controllers/videos.php
>
> Line Number: 281

Comment: ehm, as it says, you can find that call in the file `controllers/videos.php`...

Answer (score 1):

Edit the file `controllers/videos.php` and replace the `file_get_contents()` call with `libcurl` calls as shown here [PHP : how can use curl instead file_get_contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540800/php-how-can-use-curl-instead-file-get-contents), so:

```
$url = "https://graph.facebook.com/" . base_url() . "videos/videos_watch/" . $id_video';
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);       
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
// do something with $data
```

Comment: (file_get_contents("https://graph.facebook.com/" . base_url() . "videos/videos_watch/" . $id_video));

Comment: added URL based on comment