# HTTP request failed! with file get contents

Tags: php, oauth, dropbox

I used OAuth for Dropbox to get access token: https://blogs.dropbox.com/developers/2012/07/using-oauth-1-0-with-the-plaintext-signature-method/

But I got error message:
Warning: file_get_contents(https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request

My PHP Code:

```
$Header = json_encode(array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0"', "oauth_signature_method" => "PLAINTEXT", "oauth_consumer_key" => "XX", "oauth_signature" => "XX"));

$Options = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => $Header,
    )
);


$Context  = stream_context_create($Options);
$Result = file_get_contents("https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token", false, $Context);

print_r($Result);
```

Comment: Try to go for CURL.  check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8543512/4388034

Comment: also check this link it will explain you way better the usage : http://fabi.me/en/php-projects/dropphp-dropbox-api-client/comment-page-2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the documentation at http://php.net/manual/en/context.http.php, it looks like the `header` option is just a normal string, not json_encoded. Alternatively, you should be able to use a numerically indexed array of headers, like so:

```
$Header = array(
"Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", oauth_consumer_key=\"XXXXX\", oauth_signature=\"XXXXX&\"\r\n"
);

$Options = array('http' =>
    array(
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'header'  => $Header,
    )
);
```

Comment: Hm, try this for the header instead: `$header = 'Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0", oauth_signature_method="PLAINTEXT",
oauth_consumer_key="<app-key>", oauth_signature="<app-secret>&"'` (All one long string, not in an array.)

Comment: Mr. kunruh, I tried your code, but not working with me :(

Comment: This is the only other guess I have: 
`$header = "Authorization: OAuth oauth_version=\"1.0\", oauth_signature_method=\"PLAINTEXT\", oauth_consumer_key=\"<app-key>\", oauth_signature=\"<app-secret>&\"\r\n"`.


Also make sure you are replacing the `<app-key>` and `<app-secret>` with your correct credentials.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$Header = json_encode(array('Authorization: OAuth oauth_version="1.0"', "oauth_signature_method" => "PLAINTEXT", "oauth_consumer_key" => "XX", "oauth_signature" => "XX"));
```

The `header` paramter in an http stream is either a simple single string containing one single header `key: value`, or an array of `key: value` strings. You're stuffing in a single json string as your header, meaning it's NOT a valid http header.

Remove the json_encode() part completely. `$Header = array(...)` is all you need.