# Php curl function api

Tags: php, api, curl

Can someone help me make a curl function in php to access this api service

```
curl -v -u :xxxxx-2573-440e-8adc-cc23bb019db9 
https://api.paylike.io/transactions/56ccbfe1b31be55xxxxx
```

currently I have this but I get 403 error

```
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://api.paylike.io/transactions/556ccbfe1b31be55xxxxx");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, 'xxxxx-2573-440e-8adc-cc23bb019db9');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type:application/json", "Cache-Control:no-cache"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
$output = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8540800/php-how-can-use-curl-instead-file-get-contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the `CURLOPT_POST` use, the curl command line uses GET.

The string you set with `CURLOPT_USERPWD` doesn't start with a colon, which your command line version does (as set with `-u`).

Comment: thanks, works perfectly